# Calculate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \int\limits_0^1 \ln(1+\sin(tx))dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

> Calculate $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\int_0^1\ln(1+\sin(tx))dt$$

**My try:**
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \int_0^1 \ln (1+ \sin (tx)) dt=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} ([t \ln (1+\sin (tx))]^1_0 - \int_0^1 \frac{t \cos (tx) x}{1+ \sin (tx)} dt)$$
Then I want to use: $$u=1+\sin (tx), du=\cos (tx) x$$
But then I have: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}([t \ln (1+\sin (tx))]^1_0 - \int_1^{1+\sin x} \frac{\arcsin(u-1)}{ux} du)$$
So I think my idea about $u$ is not helpfull and I need other idea.
Can you help me?

Comment: Just an idea (that might or might not work). Have you tried to interchange limit and integral? Of course, if you do this you must justify it somehow, e.g. using dominated convergence theorem with majorant $\ln(2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary to compute the integral explicitly. The following estimate is sufficient to determine the limit:

If $0 \le x \le \pi$ then $\sin(tx) \ge 0$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$, so that
$$
 0 \le \ln (1+ \sin (tx)) \le \sin(tx) \le tx
$$
and therefore 
$$
0 \le  \int_0^1 \ln (1+ \sin (tx)) dt \le \frac x2 \, .
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $\ln(1+\sin(xt)) \le \ln 2$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ and $x > 0$. Since $\ln 2$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to obtain

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\int_0^1 \ln(1+\sin(xt))\,dt = \int_0^1 \lim_{x\to 0^+} \ln(1+\sin(xt)) \,dt = \int_0^1\ln 1\,dt = 0$$